# Election: minimum reputation/moderation requirements

Tags: discussion, election

Two years ago there were one or two nominations from users with low reputation and hardly any moderation track record. At the time this brought up [a discussion](https://askubuntu.com/election/4#post-419365) on raising the minimum requirements for nomination.

The 2016 election opened a few hours ago and there are already 3 nominations with scores below 5; so far there is only one with a score above 20.

If I recall correctly, the minimum is just 300 points of reputation and no moderation experience at all. Shouldn't this be raised?

Comment: I think it should be raised, also some people who put there self forward, only have 1 or 2 of the moderation badges, they definitely don't have the experience. I think as much as 3k should be required because until then, you don't even get to participate in closing questions. How can you be a moderator if you have are not even experienced in all the workings of the site? It seems crazy to me that users who still are getting used to the site, would become the ones who moderate it.

Comment: Even if I'm a candidate with a score below 20 i can second that what @MarkKirby said, there should be at least be some really recognizable afford to be seen when it comes to the review cues.

Comment: "_no moderation experience at all_" - not necessarily, as some users, even if they have little moderation experience _here_, may already have moderation experience on other SE sites.

Comment: Jonas, that does not seem to be the case. You can quickly find a candidate without any moderation experience across the whole SE universe.

Comment: @JonasCz While you are correct, there are other places to get mod experience. IMO They need the experience here too. While we are part of the SE network, every site has its own issues and quirks. Here we have a massive amount of new users every day and a very small but dedicated daily contribution base. I would like a mod who has been through this and the issues us regulars deal with every day. How can I take advice on closing questions from a user (mod on another site or not) who does not have the relative experience with the nuances of the close system? I can't.

Comment: Here, as if by magic, is a perfect example of an experienced mod, dealing with a user he understands, dealing with a potentially explosive situation, in a great and successful manner. http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15528/75060

Comment: Up to now, I think all candidates played by the rules (except those who did not sign the CoC, but they are easy to spot). There are high rep users who **certainly** would be awesome moderators. To which I tell: great, nominate yourself and I will vote for you. ;) If these users apply, they will surely get elected, overcoming the low rep users candidates. But if they do not apply, it's not the candidates' fault.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto "But if they do not apply, it's not the candidates' fault." Of course not but there needs to be an level of experience there. It is hard to choose and I am all for giving someone a chance but the mods have a tough line to walk between keeping the sites integrity and keeping the users happy, it is no small undertaking at all. We have to choose wisely or it will have a negative effect on us all.

Comment: @MarkKirby I might agree there could be an entry level, but what I'm saying is that it is not mandatory. The fact that one applies does not mean they will get elected.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Sure, I can get behind that, equal opportunity and all that.

Comment: Contrast [gaming.se], where [6 candidates](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/5) applied, all with scores ≥ 19.

Comment: Yes I agree with Mark. It should be raised. Even though I am a low rep user, I have made a comment on every candidate, and not naming any, I can only see one that is really good, and two others which are a good direction.

Comment: @CollDue96 Andrea actually did change my mind a bit on this. Perhaps I was forcing the standards I wanted on the community, we should all have the same opportunity but inexperienced users should also be made aware of there lack of experience.